# gsuite mail with phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer, google-workspace

[image]

I set up my site registration form with phpmailer and gsuite. email is working perfectly. but I getting this notifications top of the register page after registration. what should I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have enabled SMTP debugging. Check your configuration for the below.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Alternative to above constant
```

[PHPMailerSMTP Debugging](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging)

Comment: More to the point, to turn debug output off, do this: `$mail->SMTPDebug = false;`